# Need help to understand the order of execution in conjunction with async and await

Tags: swift, async-await

With the sample code below I have made a test to understand the async and await mechanism in Swift. The sequence of processes is achieved. My test prints to the console do appear in the intended sequence (step 1-4). However, what puzzles me is that the test messages, which shall appear on the UI, do not show up in the intended sequence. Both messages (`Message1` and `Message2`) appear together at the end of the entire process after step 4. So why does `Message1` not appear right after step 1 as coded?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var testasyncDone = false
    @IBOutlet weak var MyButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Message1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Message2: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func MyButton2pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("MyButton Pressed step 1")
        
        // This first message shall appear right after the button
        // is pressed
        Message1.text =  "In Button action - start"
        
        // The async task is defined and started
        testasyncDone = false
        Task.detached {
            await self.testasync()
            print("MyButton Pressed step 4")
        }
        
        // The intention of the next lines is to hold the
        // processing of the main thread until the async task is
        // completed.
        var count = 0
        repeat {
            count = count + 1
            usleep(100000)
            print (count)
        } while testasyncDone == false && count < 100
        
        // After the async task is done, the second message shall show up
        Message2.text = "In Button action - end"
    }
    
    func testasync() async {
        print("in testasync step 2")
        sleep(2)
        print("in testasync step 3")
        testasyncDone = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> So why does Message1 not appear right after step 1 as coded?

Because you are blocking the main thread with your `repeat`-`while` loop. Your code is a perfect demonstration of why you should *never* block the main thread, as the UI cannot be updated until you free up the main thread. Any system events will be prevented, too. If you block the main thread for long enough, you even risk having your app unceremoniously killed by the [watchdog process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations/) (designated with the termination code `0x8badf00d`, pronounced “ate bad food”).

Your code says:

```swift
// The intention of the next lines is to hold the
// processing of the main thread until the async task is
// completed.
```

That *is* the problem. That is why your UI has frozen. This is to be categorically avoided.

FYI, this behavior is not unique to Swift Concurrency. This issue would manifest itself if you had attempted to block the main thread waiting for something running slowly on a GCD background queue, too.

---

BTW, I noticed that `testAsync` is calling `sleep`. But, as Apple says in [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254?time=1450):

> Recall that with Swift, the language allows us to uphold a runtime contract that threads will always be able to make forward progress. It is based on this contract that we have built a cooperative thread pool to be the default executor for Swift. As you adopt Swift concurrency, it is important to ensure that you continue to maintain this contract in your code as well so that the cooperative thread pool can function optimally.

Thus you should not call `sleep` inside `testAsync`. You can use [`Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3862701-sleep), though:

```swift
func testAsync() async throws {
    print("in testAsync step 2")
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC * 2)
    print("in testAsync step 3")
    testAsyncDone = true
}
```

It looks like a traditional “sleep” API, but as [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3862701-sleep) say, this “does *not* block the underlying thread” (emphasis added).

---

Also, note that this code is not thread-safe. You are accessing `testasyncDone` from multiple threads without any synchronization. Turn on the [Thread Sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early) (TSAN), and it will report:

[image]

You can synchronize this yourself (locks or GCD are traditional mechanisms), or with the new Swift Concurrency system, we would use an actor. See WWDC 2021 video, [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/).

---

So, I suspect that this is going to trigger the response, “well, if I can’t block the main thread, then what should I do?”

Let us consider a bunch of alternatives.

1. If you really need two tasks running in parallel and coordinate this with some state variable, one method counting until the other changes the state of that variable, you could first create an `actor` to capture this state:

   ```swift
   actor TestAsyncState {
       private var _isDone = false

       func finish() {
           _isDone = true
       }

       func isDone() -> Bool {
           _isDone
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you could check this actor state:

   ```swift
   var testAsyncState = TestAsyncState()

   @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print("MyButton Pressed step 1")

       Task.detached { [self] in
           await MainActor.run { message1.text = "In Button action - start" }
           try await self.testAsync()
           print("MyButton Pressed step 4")
           await testAsyncState.finish()
       }

       Task.detached { [self] in
           // The intention of the next lines is to keep ticking
           // until the state actor isDone or we reach 100 iterations

           var count = 0
           repeat {
               count += 1
               try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC / 10)
               print(count)
           } while await !testAsyncState.isDone() && count < 100

           await MainActor.run { message2.text = "In Button action - finished" }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or, alternatively, you could bypass this `actor` state variable entirely, and just cancel the counting task when the other finishes:

   ```swift
   @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print("MyButton Pressed step 1")

       let tickingTask = Task.detached { [self] in
           // The intention of the next lines is to keep ticking
           // until this is canceled or we reach 100 iterations

           do {
               var count = 0
               repeat {
                   count += 1
                   try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC / 10)
                   print(count)
               } while !Task.isCancelled && count < 100

               await MainActor.run { message2.text = "In Button action - finished" }
           } catch {
               await MainActor.run { message2.text = "In Button action - canceled" }
           }
       }

       Task.detached { [self] in
           await MainActor.run { message1.text =  "In Button action - start" }
           try await self.testAsync()
           print("MyButton Pressed step 4")
           tickingTask.cancel()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Or, if you just wanted to do something on the main thread when the `async` method is done, just put it after the method that you are awaiting:

   ```swift
   @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print("MyButton Pressed step 1")

       Task.detached { [self] in
           await MainActor.run { message1.text =  "In Button action - start" }
           try await self.testAsync()
           print("MyButton Pressed step 4")

           // put whatever you want on the main actor here, e.g.

           await MainActor.run { message2.text = "In Button action - finished" }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Or, if you wanted a ticking timer on the main thread and you want to cancel it when the async task is done:

   ```swift
   @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print("MyButton Pressed step 1")

       var count = 0

       let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
           count += 1
           print(count)
       }

       Task.detached { [self] in
           await MainActor.run { message1.text =  "In Button action - start" }
           try await self.testAsync()
           print("MyButton Pressed step 4")

           // put whatever you want on the main actor here, e.g.

           await MainActor.run {
               timer.invalidate()
               message2.text = "In Button action - finished"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

There are lots of ways to skin the cat. But, the key is that none of these block the main thread (or any thread, for that matter), but we can initiate whatever needs to happen on the main thread at the end of the `async` task.